# Filter videos for children youtube API

Tags: ios, video, filter, youtube-api

I am developing an iOS video player app for children. Is there a way to filter youtube videos for children by using youtube api.

Answer (score 1):

May be i'm wrong, but I think there there is no specific filter youtube videos,

but you can set `safeSearch=strict` or

search in [education category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_education)